# Can I manually override the root for testing webpages locally?

Tags: html, file

On my webpages, I typically have something like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'/>
```

However, the problem with that is if I am testing my website on my computer, I will store it in a folder like `C:/Websites/My Websites/` (for example). The problem is that when I test it locally, `/global.css` points to `C:/global.css`, because the root is the C drive.

Is there a way to manually override this root so I can test my webpages locally? If so, how? If not, is there any other way to enable me to test these pages locally?

Comment: That can be done with the help of virtual hosts, but it is not very elegant. The problem is that you are using absolute paths in the first place. Don't, use relative paths instead. It is much more portable.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, but `/something` certainly is not a relative path.

Comment: @Quentin: sorry, but page 22 clearly supports my point of view. And in section 4.2 which you mention: "A
   relative reference that begins with a single slash character is
   termed an absolute-path reference"

Comment: @Quentin: you confuse URI and path. I never talked about absolute URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sensibly.

Just install a web server on your development machine (and test via `http://localhost`). This will also be useful when you need to develop server side code.

Comment: IIS is very easy to enable in windows.

Answer (score 0):

try 'global.css' without the slash at the beginning. It will point to the directory you are in at the time.

EDIT: There seems to be some confusion:
you can traverse directories using something like 'cssFile/global.css.'
Also, you can use *../global.css' to traverse upwards.

That should help you find the file you need.

Still, i agree that using a local server is the right way to go.

Comment: I don't store `global.css` in *every single folder* of my website, though. -1

Comment: This is not a reply to the question, thus should only get posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: Still no - I won't know how many directories deep *each file* in my entire website is, and I do not want to manually change it every time

Comment: @Doorknob - well, then the answer is no. install a web server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [relative paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29). So if both the HTML and the referenced CSS file live in `C:/Websites/My Websites/`, you'd use `global.css` or `./global.css`.

Alternatively, you can run a local web server and set its document root to `C:/Websites/My Websites/`. You can then reference any linked resources (inter-site links and paths to images, CSS and JS) with the absolute path notation, e.g. `/global.css`, `/images/something.png`, `/scripts/foo/bar.js`. The advantage of using absolute paths is that you don't have to change the paths to resources in an HTML file if you move the HTML file up or down in the folder hierarchy.

For quick and easy local testing of static sites (plain HTML/CSS/JavaScript), I'd recommend [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/). It's a tiny exe that doesn't need installation, just drop it anywhere, tell it what your document root directory should be, and you can get going.

For more fully-featured development environments (Apache server, PHP, databases), look at WAMP, XAMPP or Uniform Server.